# Problems occurs when removed one object within Cocos CCARRAY_FOREACH

Tags: c++, enums, cocos2d-x-3.0

**Background**:

1. ***Cocos Version***: 3.0alpha
2. ***Language***: C++

**Problems**:

Within one CCARRAY_FOREACH, it returned wrong&duplicated Object when removed one Object from the previous cycle.

**Test Codes**:

```
__Array* test = __Array::create();
test->retain();
Sprite *item1 = Sprite::create();
Sprite *item2 = Sprite::create();
Sprite *item3 = Sprite::create();

test->addObject(item1);
test->addObject(item2);
test->addObject(item3);

Object *it = NULL;
int index = 0;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(test, it)
{
    log("[Enum] Index: %d Get: %X", index++, it);
}
it = NULL;
index = 0;
CCARRAY_FOREACH(test, it)
{
    log("[Rmoved] Index: %d Get: %X", index++, it);
    test->removeObject(it);
}
```

**Output**:

[Enum] Index: 0 Get: 90DFB88

[Enum] Index: 1 Get: 90E0030

[Enum] Index: 2 Get: 90E04D8

[Rmoved] Index: 0 Get: 90DFB88

[Rmoved] Index: 1 Get: **90E04D8**

[Rmoved] Index: 2 Get: **90E04D8**

**Questions**:

Is there anything wrong I did? I checked the codes with other developers' posted on the internet. It seems almost same.

I am curious no one met this problem before.

If not, we have to patch this hole in our codes when using **CCARRAY_FOREACH**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the better solution should use std::vector or cocos::Vector.

```
Vector<Sprite*>* test = new Vector<Sprite*>();

Sprite *item1 = Sprite::create();
Sprite *item2 = Sprite::create();
Sprite *item3 = Sprite::create();

test->pushBack(item1);
test->pushBack(item2);
test->pushBack(item3);

int index = 0;
Vector<Sprite*>::iterator it = test->begin();
while (it != test->end())
{
    log("[Enum] Index: %d Get: %X", index++, *it);
    ++it;
}

index = 0;
it = test->begin();
while(it != test->end())
{
    log("[Rmoved] Index: %d Get: %X", index++, *it);
    if(isRemovable)
    {
        it = test->erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```